# Unable to click on one of the items in a drop down list using selenium (python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click on the 'Search photos' button on flickr (image below including the html).

I have tried the following:

```
sp = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('/search/?text=tennis%20shoes')
sp.click()

sp = browser.find_element_by_name('Select photos')
sp.click()

searchPhotos = browser.find_element_by_class_name('Search photos')
searchPhotos.click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//class[@name='Search photos']").click()
```

But none of them seem to work. I am learning how to do this, including how to use xpath, so maybe I am not using it correctly. Any advice to point me in the right direction?

EDIT: full section of code to answer comment below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/Users/home/Box/Temp-to delete')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'png/jpg')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')

browser.get('https://www.flickr.com/')
searchBar = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#search-field')
searchBar.send_keys(searchTerm)

browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@data-track='autosuggestNavigate_searchPhotos']").click()
```

Using firefox 72.0.2 (64-bit), python3, geckodriver v0.26.0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solved it* Just had to hit ENTER for the photos results page to show. Here is the single line of code I changed:

```
    searchBar.send_keys(searchTerm, Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that this will work, only when the _Search Photos_ option is on first place. If it will be moved, you will choose other option.

Answer (score 0):

The path used in your XPath won't work. Try this one `.//*[@data-track='autosuggestNavigate_searchPhotos']`.

The *.//* tells Selenium so search anywhere in the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_htmldom.asp). The asterisk (*) will make Selenium to look for any element (no matter if it is div, li or any other [HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/)). Then it will check which element has the *data-track* attribute, with value *autosuggestNavigate_searchPhotos*. Since there is only one element like this, we are fine.

I advise to read more about XPath and train a bit, you may start [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, but I am getting the error as: 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .//*[@data-track='autosuggestNavigate_searchPhotos']'

Comment: Could you update your question with the latest code you have used? The XPath I have provided is for the element on the list, so you still have to click on the dropdown before.

Comment: Updated to add the code. And not clear on what you are saying, because my  problem in the first place lies in not being able to click on the dropdown, which is what I thought your code snippet addressed.

Comment: My answer was about clicking the Search Photos option.